# Raphael.js - filling a combined custom shape

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have an SVG path that is a shape within another shape. If I add a stroke to the path the shape is outlined perfectly so I know the path is correct.

However if I choose to fill the shape, both the outer and inner shape are filled NOT the area between the 2. I am just using the 'fill' color attribute.

Any ideas why this is happening? It's not something I ever imagined occurring.

Thanks

Comment: I'd post up the svg somewhere.

Comment: Look at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillRuleProperty for an explanation.